# Unable to communicate between components using Angular2 Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to communicate between two component using Subject

```
private onAdd = new Subject<any>();
onAdd$ = this.onAdd.asObservable();

this.onAdd.next(event);
```

These i have written i service:

I am listening them like this in other component inside ngOninit

```
this.service.onAdd$.subscribe((alert) => {
            console.log('Component---  ' + alert);
         });
```

Two things:

1. this.onAdd.next(event); ---> undefined
2. console.log('Component---  ' + alert); ----> Not getting printed

So, i can assure that my event is not getting communicated to other component i am not able to figure out what is the problem. Can anybody help me.

Comment: dont you think `onAddAlerts$` should be replaced by `onAdd$` and it should start working !

Comment: @micronyks it was a typo.

Comment: Are you using `providers:['your-service']` metadata property in component?

Comment: @micronyks i am using that in my AppModule providers:[ ] section

Comment: Your code example is ok, but it missing a place where `this.onAdd.next(event);` performed. Right after `onAdd$` creation?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a 'ReplaySubject' or a 'BehaviorSubject', if the 'next' method is called before the component subscribes to the subject, it won't receive any data until the next method is called again.

EDIT - Try this simple working plunkr example - http://plnkr.co/edit/34Zj0QB5chEYj7g1vRmN

In the plunkr, you can see that if you increment the value many times before subscribing, your component will automatically receive the last value when you hit the subscribe button using a ReplaySubject. With a normal subject, when you subscribe, the value won't be shown until you click the 'increment' button again.

If you call

```
 this.onAdd.next(event);
```

Again after the component subscribes to it, it should receive the data.

or try changing to a replay subject, so the subject will send the last emitted value when it receives a new subscriber

```
 private onAdd = new ReplaySubject<any>();
```

Just make sure you import it

```
 import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';
```

Comment: Can you provide more complete code? Its hard to troubleshoot further without additional context.

Comment: where are you defining event? What is event? I figured you had context for it and just weren't sharing it. But event wont mean anything unless its been defined somewhere.

Comment: event is nothing just a json object

Comment: I'm trying to make a plunkr for you but it doesn't seem that rxjs  will work on a plunker.  :-(

Comment: many thanks I'll try to figure out if i does not get answer here :(

Comment: many many thanks i tried this but not working with my case may be i am doing something wrong.

Comment: I got my solution actually the implementation was correct but the component which is subscribed to listen to the event was not loaded at all. So, i used that component selector to place in app.component.html and now its working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refactor your service like this.
myService.service.ts

```
class MyService {
 private onAdd = new Subject<any>();

   sendonAdd(value) {
     this.onAdd.next(value);
   }
   getonAdd(){
    return this.onAdd.asObservable();
   }
}
```

now inject this service in component where u want to set onadd value by calling sendonAdd(). And in the other component call getonAdd() and subscribe to it. Hope this helps! If it does, accept my answer.